# Enumerating sub-folders and saving the records from flat file to SQL

Tags: sql-server, ssis, bids

I've a root folder which contains few CoNum folder and they contain CycleDate folder, every CycleDate folder contain a file named N718010.txt which contains comma separated records whom I want to insert into SQL database table. How can I achieve the same? I'm a beginner in the SSIS world.

[image]

I followed this url- http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.in/2011/01/foreach-folder-enumerator.html

but it is incomplete and this ended up getting the path in a variable (xmldoc) like:

[image]

How can I get these records saved to the SQL database table? Note: I also have to save CoNum and CycleDate to the table with each record.

Comment: Does the files contains the same information? Columns etc.

Comment: No, I've to save 2 extra columns which are CoNum and CycleDate. Rest columns match.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do, is just to use a simple `Foreach Loop Container`

You can read about a very basic method [here](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Looping-over-files-with-the-Foreach-Loop.aspx)

To get CoNum and CycleDate, you can just substring your FullPath variable in a derived column.

Comment: I got the path in XML node form in a variable, next what to do and how?

Comment: But why do you need it in XML node? You can just hardcode it to D:\SSISDAta\AMLFILES

Comment: I followed this URL- http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.in/2011/01/foreach-folder-enumerator.html

Comment: @LogicalDesk dont use that. Harcode your main path in a variable and do as i linked